# WebMatrix DynamicRecord - get column value without knowing any column name of seleted table

Tags: c#

i got a thing to ask. I'm using Razor engine

`var data = db.Querry(selectStatemnet)` -> this return a Set of data.

using this :

`foreach ( var row in data )` -> i get a row

Here is my problem :

`@row.columnName` -> return the value of that column (if i know all the column names in table being selected)

So how can i do this :

`var/string myColumnName = columnName` -> as i don't know all the column names, i have to get it from whereelse -> i have to do this. I don't want to use WebGrid, because i don't know how to controll it.

And i want this :

```
@row.myColumnName
```

I tried, but `@row.myColumnName` does not do what i want, it checked and saying there is no myColumnName column. It's like i can't not do it this way. I MUST KNOW ALL THE COLUMN NAME?

I also tried : `@row.@myColumName` -> this does return something like this : WebMatrix.DynamicRecord.mycolumnvalue -> this case, the program just `ToString()` everything.

I dont' want to use WEBGRID, as i have less controll.

So what do i do?